# Adding arguments to Python port scanner directly using command lines

Tags: python, sockets, terminal, port, sys

I created a Python portscanner:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import socket


def get_accessible_ports(address, min_port, max_port):
   found_ports = []

   # write code here
   while min_port <= max_port:
       s = socket.socket()
       try:
           s.connect((address, min_port))
       except:
           min_port += 1
           continue
       else:
           found_ports.append(min_port)#
           min_port += 1
           continue

   return found_ports


def main(argv):
   address = sys.argv[1]
   min_port = int(sys.argv[2])
   max_port = int(sys.argv[3])
   ports = get_accessible_ports(address, min_port, max_port)
   for p in ports:
       print(p)
     

# TMC is the testing environment
# This makes sure the main function is not called immediatedly
# when TMC imports this module
if __name__ == "__main__":
   if len(sys.argv) != 4:
       print('usage: python %s address min_port max_port' % sys.argv[0])
   else:
       main(sys.argv)
```

Then I wanted to use that port scanner to **read a message in a port between 20050 and 20150** with the localhost (my computer as the address).

This is what I tried running on the terminal:

```
python3 portscanner.py 192.168.0.10 20050 20150
```

However, nothing showed up. Is there anything I can do for me to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Your Program is showing nothing as output because you have `continue` statement in your `try` `except` block `Exception handling`. So if any error happens the `while` loop will keep continuing and the return value from `get_accessible_ports` will be empty list hence no output:

Try to add logging information when an error happens then you will be able to see if anything has happened in the try block that causes an error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import socket


def get_accessible_ports(address, min_port, max_port):
   found_ports = []

   # write code here
   while min_port <= max_port:

       s = socket.socket()
       try:
           s.connect((address, min_port))
       except Exception as e:
           print("Error occured", e)
           min_port += 1
           continue
       else:
           found_ports.append(min_port)#
           min_port += 1
           continue

   return found_ports


def main(argv):
   address = sys.argv[1]
   min_port = int(sys.argv[2])
   max_port = int(sys.argv[3])
   ports = get_accessible_ports(address, min_port, max_port)
   for p in ports:
       print(p)


# TMC is the testing environment
# This makes sure the main function is not called immediatedly
# when TMC imports this module
if __name__ == "__main__":
   if len(sys.argv) != 4:
       print('usage: python %s address min_port max_port' % sys.argv[0])
   else:
       main(sys.argv)
```

Alternatively, you can add check for `found_ports` list before your return block, such that you can notify with some verbose information when the list `found_ports` is empty after the `while` loop completes.

However, Your code runs fine it just couldn't see any output just because all the port you scanned resulted in an error:

try this:

```
python portscanner.py 127.0.0.1 79 80
[Errno 61] Connection refused
80
```